Почему функция крафта в mineflayer не работает?
Я создаю mineflayer бота с gpt но недавно столкнулся с проблемой - функция крафта просто отказывается работать, а в интернете нет ни одного нормального гайда на эту тему:
function craft(recipeName, count) {
    const recipes = bot.recipesFor(recipeName); // Получаем рецепт
    console.log("Найденные рецепты для крафта:", recipes);

    if (recipes.length === 0) {
        history.push({ role: "system", content: 'Рецепт не найден!' });
        console.log("Рецепт не найден!");
        return;
    }

    const recipe = recipes[0]; // Получаем первый рецепт
    console.log("Требуемые ингредиенты рецепта:", recipe.ingredients);

    // Проверка, что у бота есть все необходимые материалы
    const materialsAvailable = Array.isArray(recipe.ingredients) && recipe.ingredients.every(ingredient => {
        const inventoryItem = bot.inventory.items().find(item => item.name === ingredient.name);
        return inventoryItem && inventoryItem.count >= ingredient.count;
    });

    if (!materialsAvailable) {
        console.log(bot.inventory.items());
        console.log('У бота недостаточно материалов для крафта.');
        history.push({ role: "system", content: 'У бота недостаточно материалов для крафта.' });
        return;
    }

    // Открытие крафтового меню (внутреннего окна бота)
    bot.openCraftingTable((err, craftingTable) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Ошибка при открытии крафтового меню:", err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Крафтовое меню открыто.");

        // Заполнение крафтовой сетки (4 слота)
        const grid = craftingTable.slots.slice(0, 4); // Получаем первые 4 слота для ингредиентов

        recipe.ingredients.forEach((ingredient, index) => {
            const inventoryItem = bot.inventory.items().find(item => item.name === ingredient.name);
            if (inventoryItem) {
                bot.putInSlot(grid[index], inventoryItem, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Ошибка при размещении ингредиента в сетке:", err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Запуск крафта
        craftingTable.craft(recipe, count, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Ошибка при крафте:", err);
                history.push({ role: "system", content: 'Ошибка при крафте!' });
            } else {
                console.log("Крафт завершён успешно.");
                history.push({ role: "system", content: 'Крафт завершён успешно.' });
            }
        });
    });
}

Вот полный код: https://pastebin.com/huXnA5Ht
Ожидалось что бот скрафтит верстак из предметов в его инвентаре но вот вывод консоли:
Получено сообщение: скрафти верстак
Ответ от GPT: {
  "id": "chatcmpl-AShOfyCrt2ftKY7IGZz1AJ716Crx7",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1731403365,
  "model": "gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": null,
        "function_call": {
          "name": "craft",
          "arguments": "{\"item\":\"crafting_table\",\"amount\":1}"
        },
        "refusal": null
      },
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "function_call"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 703,
    "completion_tokens": 20,
    "total_tokens": 723,
    "prompt_tokens_details": {
      "cached_tokens": 0,
      "audio_tokens": 0
    },
    "completion_tokens_details": {
      "reasoning_tokens": 0,
      "audio_tokens": 0,
      "accepted_prediction_tokens": 0,
      "rejected_prediction_tokens": 0
    }
  },
  "system_fingerprint": "fp_9b78b61c52"
}
crafting_table
1
Найденные рецепты для крафта: []
Рецепт не найден!
GPTChel крафтит: crafting_table
^C


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Он же пишет, что рецепт не найден. Значит его нет. У вас проблема с получение рецептов
